# List of available transformations between two coordinates system in epsg using geotools

Tags: coordinate-system, geotools, epsg

How we can have the list of available transformation between two coordinate systems using geotools? e.g. the list provided of epsg.io between EPSG:32066 and EPSG:4326

https://epsg.io/32066

Java snippet using geotools would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is not possible (though Andrea may correct me) -

Consider the following program:

```
CoordinateReferenceSystem src = CRS.decode("EPSG:32066");
CoordinateReferenceSystem dest = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");
System.out.println(src);
MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(src, dest, false);
System.out.println(transform);
```

Which outputs:

```
PROJCS["NAD27 / BLM 16N (ftUS)", 
  GEOGCS["NAD27", 
    DATUM["North American Datum 1927", 
      SPHEROID["Clarke 1866", 6378206.4, 294.9786982138982, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7008"]], 
      TOWGS84[2.478, 149.752, 197.726, 0.526, -0.498, 0.501, 0.685], 
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","6267"]], 
    PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
    UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
    AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], 
    AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4267"]], 
  PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator", AUTHORITY["EPSG","9807"]], 
  PARAMETER["central_meridian", -87.0], 
  PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["scale_factor", 0.9996], 
  PARAMETER["false_easting", 1640416.67], 
  PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0], 
  UNIT["ft_survey_us", 0.3048006096012192], 
  AXIS["Easting", EAST], 
  AXIS["Northing", NORTH], 
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","32066"]]
CONCAT_MT[PARAM_MT["Affine", 
    PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
    PARAMETER["num_col", 3], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 0.3048006096012192], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_1", 0.3048006096012192]], 
  INVERSE_MT[PARAM_MT["Transverse_Mercator", 
      PARAMETER["semi_major", 6378206.4], 
      PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6356583.8], 
      PARAMETER["central_meridian", -87.0], 
      PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
      PARAMETER["scale_factor", 0.9996], 
      PARAMETER["false_easting", 500000.00101600203], 
      PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0]]], 
  PARAM_MT["Ellipsoid_To_Geocentric", 
    PARAMETER["dim", 2], 
    PARAMETER["semi_major", 6378206.4], 
    PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6356583.8]], 
  PARAM_MT["Affine", 
    PARAMETER["num_row", 4], 
    PARAMETER["num_col", 4], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 1.000000685], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_1", -0.00000242891820616661], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_2", -0.0000024143737857704], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_3", 2.478], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_0", 0.00000242891820616661], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_1", 1.000000685], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_2", -0.00000255012170946833], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_3", 149.752], 
    PARAMETER["elt_2_0", 0.0000024143737857704], 
    PARAMETER["elt_2_1", 0.00000255012170946833], 
    PARAMETER["elt_2_2", 1.000000685], 
    PARAMETER["elt_2_3", 197.726]], 
  PARAM_MT["Geocentric_To_Ellipsoid", 
    PARAMETER["dim", 2], 
    PARAMETER["semi_major", 6378137.0], 
    PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6356752.314245179]], 
  PARAM_MT["Affine", 
    PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
    PARAMETER["num_col", 3], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 0.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_1", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_0", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_1", 0.0]]]
```

This will have come from the EPSG (now OPG) database, note the TOWGS84 parameter which defines the Affine Transform in the middle of the transform.

If I [add](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/configuration/crshandling/coordtransforms.html#add-grid-shift-transform-files) the [NADCON transform files](https://www.ngs.noaa.gov/PC_PROD/NADCON/) to my `org.geotools.referencing.factory.gridshift` folder - I can get the following transform:

```
CONCAT_MT[PARAM_MT["Affine", 
    PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
    PARAMETER["num_col", 3], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 0.3048006096012192], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_1", 0.3048006096012192]], 
  INVERSE_MT[PARAM_MT["Transverse_Mercator", 
      PARAMETER["semi_major", 6378206.4], 
      PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6356583.8], 
      PARAMETER["central_meridian", -87.0], 
      PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
      PARAMETER["scale_factor", 0.9996], 
      PARAMETER["false_easting", 500000.00101600203], 
      PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0]]], 
  PARAM_MT["NADCON", 
    PARAMETER["Latitude difference file", "conus.las"], 
    PARAMETER["Longitude difference file", "conus.los"]], 
  PARAM_MT["NADCON", 
    PARAMETER["Latitude difference file", "emhpgn.las"], 
    PARAMETER["Longitude difference file", "emhpgn.los"]], 
  PARAM_MT["Affine", 
    PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
    PARAMETER["num_col", 3], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 0.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_1", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_0", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_1", 0.0]]]
```

It looks like you might need to [define a custom transform](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/configuration/crshandling/coordtransforms.html#define-a-custom-coordinate-operation) to make sure you use a specific transformation.